# C How can i access values in misaligned memory

Tags: c, memory-alignment

I have a block of memory, which contains data, how can i access the data, even if it is misaligned, platform indepently? The data is mostly 8 and 32 bit values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want complete platform independence, declare an `unsigned char *` to point to the memory, pick up bytes, and use '|' and '<<' as needed to assemble the values.

Answer (score 1):

You can memcpy to an aligned one:

```
void f(void *var_16bit_alignment) {
  uint16_t v;
  memcpy(&v, var_16bit_alignment, sizeof(v);
  // access to v are aligned now!
}
```

Note that use of `uint16_t *` as a type for the parameter is already undefined behavior, and that the type of v can be adjusted for your needs (`uint32_t`, ...).  Note also that this does not deal with endianess, but it easy expand with `ntohs` or similar.

For completeness, 8 bit data is already aligned (unless you are using a very weird platform).